# Understanding Event Coincidence Analysis from CoinCalc R package

Tags: r, plot, coin-flipping

I have two binarized events (eventA and eventB), I want to know if there is any coincidence in these two events. So I'll use the new Package CoinCalc to investigate the potential relation between these two.

```
library(CoinCalc) #note that the package is not visible (at least for) me in CRAN. I got it from GitHub https://github.com/JonatanSiegmund/CoinCalc
```

## two binary events

```
eventA= c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)

eventB = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0)
```

## run ECA analysis

ca.out <- CC.eca.ts(eventA, eventB,delT=2,tau=2)

## this yields:

## $`NH precursor`

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6O9.jpg) TRUE

## $`NH trigger`

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6O9.jpg) FALSE

## $`p-value precursor`

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6O9.jpg) 0.2544052

## $`p-value trigger`

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6O9.jpg) 0.003287963

## $`precursor coincidence rate`

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6O9.jpg) 0.8243243

## $`trigger coincidence rate`

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6O9.jpg) 0.9285714

I want to make sure I'm understanding this properly. Based on the results, the null hypothesis can only be rejected for the trigger, which is statistically significant at the 0.003 level, and the coincidence rate is 0.92 (very high, is this equivalent to R2?). Can this be interpreted that eventB has a strong influence on eventA, but not the opposite?

Then I can plot these two events using the CC.plot function:

```
CC.plot(eventA,eventB,dates=c(1900:2040),delT=2, tau=2, seriesAname = 'EventA', seriesBname = 'EventB')
```

Which yields:
[image: CC.plot output using binary data]

Is there any way to modify the graphical parameters in CC.plot? The dummy years are not visible in this plot. I'd like to change fonts, size, colours, etc. Is there any way to draw the same figure by calling the model output (ca.out)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions:

Question #1: The most important problem that I see in your example is that your events are not "rare". Therefore the most important pre-condition of the analytical significance test that you used by default (**sigtest="poisson"**) in not fulfilled. Another "problem" is, that the events in both series seem to be clustered (may also be an effect of the high number of events). I would recommend to use **sigtest="shuffle.surrogate"** which is more appropriate for this case. More information about the significance test can be found at Siegmund et al. 2017 (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300416305489)
Executing this reveals that both coincidence rates are not significant. By the way: with such a high number of events it is extremely unlikely that you would ever get a 'significant coincidence rate', because the chance that simultaneities occur by random is very very high.

Nevertheless, if the trigger coincidence rate would be significant and the precursor not, your interpretation is a possible one.

Question #2: The problem with the plot is again, that there are too many events (compared to what the method was originally designed for). This is why everything looks so messy. The function was ment to be more like a help to explain how the method works and what you have done. 
If you e.g. only plot e.g. 20 years of your data

```
CC.plot(eventA[120:140],eventB[120:140],dates=c(2020:2040),delT=2, tau=2, seriesAname = 'EventA', seriesBname = 'EventB')
```

you will get a much better image, that yet, due to the high event-density of almost 50%, is not very nice.
[CoinCalc plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LufDY.png)

For now, there are no options to change the plot parameters. This might come for a future version of the package.

I hope that this helps you a bit!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it's very helpful and clarifying.